# jquery, options value

Tags: jquery

whats wrong with my code?

Why i don't get options value(in my sample - 1)?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#number option:selected").length > 0)
    {   
        alert('selected id:' + $("#number option:selected"));
    }
});
</script>
<body>
<select id = "number" name = "number">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you're trying to alert the jQuery object itself, not the value that's selected.

Instead use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('selected id:' + $("#numberd").val());
});
```

This will get the value of the select.  If you want the **text** (e.g. "one") then use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('selected id:' + $("#numberd option:selected").text());
});
```

The first `<option>` will always be selected if nothing else is, so there's no need to check the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of matches here.

Answer (score 2):

That only returns the element. You need to get the `value` property of the element.

You can use [jQuery's `.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value.

```
alert( 'selected id:' + $("#number option:selected").val() );
```

And actually, you can call `.val()` on the `<select>` element itself instead of getting the selected `<option>`.

```
alert( 'selected id:' + $("#number").val() );
```